# How can I calculate this term?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

How do I evaluate a term of the form

$$\frac{\langle v_1, x_2 \rangle}{\Vert v_1 \Vert}?$$

I know that the denominator is the norm. However, how can I calculate the numerator?
In my example, $v_1= (1,  2,  3)$ and $x_2 = ( 1,  -2,  3)$.

Thanks.

Comment: It's the dot product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product BTW, these aren't statements but expressions.

Comment: This is the inner product of the Euclidean Space, the dot product or scalar product  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Euclidean_space . The denominator is the square of the norm, not the normal

Comment: There is insufficient context to interpret this correctly. Is the numerator a dot product? If so, you should denote it as $v_1 \cdot x_2$. Angle brackets typically enclose the components of a vector.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression in the numerator is the so-called [standard inner product in Euclidean space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Euclidean_space) of two vectors, which can be evaluated as follows:

$$\left\langle \begin{pmatrix}
a \\ b \\ c
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{pmatrix} \right\rangle = ax + by+cz.$$
Note that with this notation, we can define $\Vert v \Vert = \sqrt{\langle v, v \rangle}.$
Substituting your specific values, we obtain
$$\frac{\langle v_1, x_2\rangle}{\Vert v_1 \Vert} = \frac{1 -4 + 9}{\sqrt{1 + 4 + 9}} = \frac{6}{\sqrt{14}}.$$